# Slim3: Routing with "where" (like on Laravel)

Tags: slim

i'm looking for a similar solution for Slim3:

```
Route::get('/{name}', function ($name) {
//
}) ->where('name', 'bars|clubs|discos');
```

So a route should handle 3 different names.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#regular-expression-matching), you can add a regular expression inside the placeholder definition

```
$app->get('/{name:bars|clubs|discos}', callback);
```